# UIAlertview not adding UIDatePicker when i click on textfield?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uialertview, uidatepicker, sdcalertview

UIAlertview not adding UIDatePicker when i click on textfield?

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Preferences"
                                                message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    pickerView=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,246,150)];
    pickerView.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [alert addSubview:pickerView];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: its shown only alertview not datepicker inside alertview

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 doesn't support adding subviews to its hierarchy anymore. That's why I wrote [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView). It adds a contentView property which you can use to add any other view to the alert.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 `UIAlertView's` view hierarchy has been changed , so now you cant add any view to the `UIAleartView`

Comment: You can create your custom Aleartview or search for custom aleartview

Answer (score 0):

Adding subviews to a UIAlertView is not supported anymore, starting in iOS7. You can use third party view like: https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code**

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello"
     message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Stamp", nil];
    UIDatePicker  *pickerView=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,246,150)];
    pickerView.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
     myAlertView.tag=101;
     [myAlertView show];
    UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, myAlertView.bounds.size.height, 320, 216)];
    // Add picker to alert
    [myAlertView addSubview:picker];
    // Adjust the alerts bounds
    myAlertView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 + 20, myAlertView.bounds.size.height + 216 + 20);
     [myAlertView release];
```

Comment: Won't work. `addSubview:` on `UIAlertView` will do absolutely nothing in iOS 7.

Comment: -1 as this is incorrect based on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html you are not allowed to modify the `UIAlertView` hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apple will not allow you to add subviews or modify the view hierarchy. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html for:

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

And see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView for:

> **Appearance of Alert Views**
>
> You cannot customize the appearance of alert views.

Going against these will get your App rejected in the Apple Review process - so I would go back and look at your design of your app.